# Pythonic way to Validate time input (only for Hr, Min, Sec)

Tags: python, datetime, validation

In my application,I am getting time input in a variable in string format e.g. `Values = '12,12,12'`.

Now i need to validate it `h<24 M<60 S<60` etc. and  i want final output in `'%H:%M:%S'` format.
To get this i tried `datetime.time().`

I had 1st tried with `values = '12'` then `'12,12,12'`.

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: values = '12'

In [3]: d = datetime.time(values)

TypeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
/mypc/test/<ipython console> in <module>()
TypeError: an integer is required

In [4]: d = datetime.time(int(values))

In [5]: d
Out[5]: datetime.time(12, 0)

In [6]: d.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
Out[6]: '12:00:00'

In [7]: s = d.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

In [8]: s
Out[8]: '12:00:00'

In [9]: values = '12,12,12'

In [10]: d = datetime.time(int(values))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '12,12,12'
```

But it works as below.

```
In [24]: datetime.time(12,12,12).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
Out[24]: '12:12:12'
```

So problem is that datetime.time() is taking input as integer and `'12,12,12'` string cannot be converted in int.

Is there any other way(otherthan regexp) to do the validation for only Hr:M:S.

Comment: you mean `M<60` and `S<60`, right? This is why you're not supposed to manually do anything with dates. It never comes out right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to unpack the values:

```
>>> values = '12,12,12'
>>> values = ast.literal_eval(values)
>>> datetime.time(*values)
datetime.time(12, 12, 12)
```

This last statement will raise an error if the time given is invalid.

To avoid problems with zero-padded numbers, as "wim" pointed, it's possible to change the  second line to:

```
values = (int(i) for i in values.split(','))
```

or

```
values = map(int, values.split(','))
```

Comment: possible gotcha with octals if the string input could be zero-padded.  otherwise very elegant with the literal eval and tuple unpacking!

Comment: I'd avoid using ast.literal_eval unless you're certain that the value is only coming from within your app (not from users). @jcollado 's answer below is the way to go.

Comment: @KFunk `ast.literal_eval` is quite safe. This is not `eval`.

Answer (score 5):

Please note that the counterpart of `strftime` is `strptime`, that is, if you need to parse a time you can use `strptime` using a format string the same way as you use `strftime` to print a time using that format string:

```
>>> import time
>>> t = time.strptime('12,12,12', '%H,%M,%S')
>>> time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', t)
'12:12:12'
```

This way, `strptime` takes care of the validation (`H<24, M<60, S<=61`):

```
>>> time.strptime('24,0,0', '%H,%M,%S')
...
ValueError: time data '24,0,0' does not match format '%H,%M,%S'
>>> time.strptime('0,60,0', '%H,%M,%S')
...
ValueError: time data '0,60,0' does not match format '%H,%M,%S'
>>> time.strptime('0,0,62', '%H,%M,%S')
...
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 2
```

Note that `strptime` allows `S<=61` as explained in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime):

> The range really is 0 to 61; this accounts for leap seconds and the (very rare) double leap seconds.

If that's a problem for you, then you probably need to parse that value in your code.